# post register with passport.authenticate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am developing a website with nodejs/express/sequelize/mysql and angularJs in front

my tree structure over here :

[image: tree structure]

Actually I am posting datas from "RegisteredController.js" :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appFoodtastic.registered', ['ngRoute'])

// Routing configuration for this module
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeprovider) {
    $routeprovider.when('/registered', {
        controller: 'RegisteredController',
        templateUrl: 'components/views/registeredView.html'
    });
}])

// Controller definition for this module
.controller('RegisteredController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    init();
    function init(){

};
    $scope.submit = function () {
        console.log($scope.user);
        $http.post('/registered', $scope.user)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("posted")
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.error(response)
        })
    }
}]);
```

To my "routes.js" file :

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("/#/login");
});


app.post('/registered', passport.authenticate('local-registered',{
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/#/registered'
}
));

// app.get('/', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
//     res.redirect("/#/registered")
// });

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/#/login'
}
));


function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/#/login');
}


}
```

Passport.js contain my hash for user password and sequelize methods to add new user, check if exist in db :

```
//load bcrypt
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function (passport, user) {

var User = user;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});


// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id).then(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            done(null, user.get());
        }
        else {
            done(user.errors, null);
        }
    });

});


passport.use('local-registered', new LocalStrategy(

    {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function (req, email, password, done) {

        var generateHash = function (password) {
            return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        };

        User.findOne({ where: { email: email } }).then(function (user) {

            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is already taken' });
            }

            else {
                var userPassword = generateHash(password);
                var data =
                    {
                        email: email,
                        password: userPassword,
                        firstname: req.body.firstname,
                        lastname: req.body.lastname
                    };

                User.create(data).then(function (newUser, created) {
                    if (!newUser) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }

                    if (newUser) {
                        return done(null, newUser);

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
));

//LOCAL SIGNIN
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy(

    {

        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

    },

    function (req, email, password, done) {

        var User = user;



        var isValidPassword = function (userpass, password) {
            return bCrypt.compareSync(password, userpass);
        }

        User.findOne({ where: { email: email } }).then(function (user) {

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Email does not exist' });
            }

            if (!isValidPassword(user.password, password)) {

                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });

            }

            var userinfo = user.get();

            return done(null, userinfo);

        }).catch(function (err) {

            console.log("Error:", err);

            return done(null, false, { message: 'Something went wrong with your Signin' });


        });

    }
));

}
```

Models and routes require are loaded in server.js :

```
var routes = require('./app/routes/routes.js')(app, passport);
//load passport strategies
require('./app/config/passport/passport.js')(passport, models.user);
```

I have an issue whith passport.authenticate when I post datas which is not redirecting to views.
User is created but I can't redirect the successRedirect and failureRedirect.

Any idea please ?

Comment: As you write api's like app.get('/login') in the same way you need to write a function for app.get('/') then it will redirect. By the way can you tell me in this /#/login /#/ login represents space or anything else???

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe, Ok ill try this and tell you if it's ok. But when I tried to app.get('/') my web site get an error like "too many redirects" it seems to be an issue with my function isLoggedIn() .The /#/ it is just for development mode. It will disappeared when the site will be in production

Comment: Check out these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706451/node-express-too-many-redirects and this one also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390921/node-js-too-many-redirect-using-middleware-redirect

Comment: Ok so I tried to change  `app.get('/', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
     res.redirect("/#/registered")
 });` to `app.all('/'')...` the problem still the same. And I also tried to change the function isLoggedIn() same as the link by add those lines `if(req.route.path !== '/login')
      res.redirect('/login');
    next();` but same error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33729318/7635845

Comment: I just want to create a user, whenever he's created, redirect him to the '/#/login", and when he's logged I want him to be redirect the to the home page "/" with a custom header (I mean change the login to logout something like that, and be able to authorize him to navigate to specialized page). So I checked your links and tried it but maybe I do not go to the right way ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153960/discussion-between-cupkek05-and-syed-ayesha-bebe).

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this code for proper redirection

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

// normal routes ===============================================================

    // show the home page (will also have our login links)
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs');
    });

    // PROFILE SECTION =========================
    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user
        });
    });

    // LOGOUT ==============================
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

// =============================================================================
// AUTHENTICATE (FIRST LOGIN) ==================================================
// =============================================================================

    // locally --------------------------------
        // LOGIN ===============================
        // show the login form
        app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
            res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });

        // process the login form
        app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));

        // SIGNUP =================================
        // show the signup form
        app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
            res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });

        // process the signup form
        app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));


// route middleware to ensure user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Here `index.ejs` , `profile.ejs` , `login.ejs` , `signup.ejs`  these are all template file nothing but static files. If you are using html files you can use html files instead of ejs files. Hope this helps.

Comment: First, thanks for help, It works but I am using html files as you can see in my tree structure then I replaced .ejs files to .html and I added those lines in my file "server.js" `app.set('views', '../Client/app/components/views');
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine','html');` but the main page seems to be load without css ..

Comment: Maybe I did a mistake with app.set('views') with path ?

Comment: You can directly use html files what the need to use it with view engine...Try to access html files directly...

Comment: I got this error when I am trying to use html files directly `Error: Cannot find module 'html'`

Comment: try to give full path of your html file like E:/syed/nodejs/tasks/mail/email verify/index.html

Comment: I got this on my "server.js" `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../Client/app'));` it should do the job. Right ?

Comment: But I just tried with full path, same problem 'cannot find module html'

Comment: This error occurs when there is no html file in path what you are mentioning...And one thing keep using of res.sendFile('E:/syed/nodejs/tasks/mail/email verify/index.html') instead of res.render('E:/syed/nodejs/tasks/mail/email verify/index.html') ; change it and let me know about it

Comment: I tried and got `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

Comment: Here's my path : `res.sendFile('C:\wamp64\www\Foodtastic\Client\app\components\views\loginView.html')`

Comment: In windows you need to use forward slash for paths like res.sendFile('C:/wamp64/www/Foodtastic/Client/app/components‌​/views/loginView.htm‌​l') Remember this every time whenever you use paths in code.

Comment: Yes sorry I did a mistake but I already tried yesterday and I could load the page but without CSS etc.. Because my "index.html" file include <header> and <footer> and <div> ng view which load the current page. But scripts, css etc.. are loaded there too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154127/discussion-between-syed-ayesha-bebe-and-cupkek05).

Answer (score 0):

On my client side, my html files are loaded in "index.html" over here :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="appFoodtastic" class="no-js">

<head>
  <title>Foodtastic</title>

  <!-- for-mobile-apps -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Foodtastic Market" />
  <script type="application/x-javascript">
    addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false);
        function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); }
  </script>
  <!-- //for-mobile-apps -->
  <!-- main slider-banner -->
<link href="resources/css/skdslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- //main slider-banner --> 
  <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <!-- font-awesome icons -->
  <link href="resources/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- //font-awesome icons -->
  <!-- js -->
  <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- //js -->
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,100italic,200,200italic,300,400italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/move-top.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/easing.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
      });
    });

  </script>
  <!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-include="'components/views/shared/headerView.html'"></div>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div ng-include="'components/views/shared/footerView.html'"></div>
  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="resources/bower/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/bower/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/AboutController.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/RegisteredController.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/ContactController.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/ProductsController.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/cartController.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/singleProductController.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/minicart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/skdslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Mini Cart
    paypal.minicart.render({
      action: '#'
    });

    if (~window.location.search.indexOf('reset=true')) {
      paypal.minicart.reset();
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The  ng-view load my current html page, and header, footer, scripts, css etc.. are loaded on this index.html file. With your proposition, page are loaded but with no CSS or scripts..